# How to convert a date string to a Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, date-parsing

How to convert a date string to a `Date` object?

An example date string:

```
31.12.2009 23:12:00
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "convert"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [Date.js library](http://www.datejs.com).

It can handle all kinds of date parsing and converting, and other date related functionality. Very handy for this kind of thing.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
var parts = "31.12.2009 23:12:00".match(/\d+/g);
new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
```

Parse it and create it.

**Note**:
Month is zero based.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript by default parses date strings with the ISO 8601 format, which is...

> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

If you can get your datetime in this format it would probably be best.  **You do not want to run into any culture issues.**  In JavaScript you can do it with [toISOString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925953). If you can't do this, you'll have to parse out the date yourself or use a library.